# Why does the RETURN statement inside useEffect seem not working during the first button click event?

Tags: reactjs

The initial render, the toggleVar is false, so RandomComponent is not invoked. After the first button click, the setInterval is invoked and runs in the background,but why does it seem like the RETURN is not triggered immediately when the useEffect exits?
That clearInterval seems to get hit on the SECOND click of the button, which is weird because the second click of the button sets the toggleVar to false, which will then prevent RandomComponent (and the useEffect inside it) from being triggered?

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const CleanupFunction = () => {
  const [toggleVar, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggleVar)}>
     Component Display
    </button>
    {toggleVar && <RandomComponent />}
  </div>
  );
};

 const RandomComponent = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Hello from useEffect');
      const intId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('This is going to be displayed every 1 second');
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intId);
        console.log('Cleared interval');
      };
   },[]);
   
   return <h1>Hello there </h1>;
  };

export default CleanupFunction;
```

This is how I understand the series of events:

1. if toggleVar is false, RandomComponent is not hit;
2. if toggleVar is true (first button click), RandomComponent is triggered

   - useEffect will run
   - 'Hello from useEffect' will be displayed
   - setInterval will be triggered and ''This is going to be displayed...' will be displayed every 1 second
   - immediately return a function which will run clearInterval thus stopping the setInterval function
   - 'Cleared interval' will be displayed
   - 'Hello there' will be displayed'
3. if toggleVar is false (second button click), RandomComponent won't get hit

I know the actual output is not the same as I expect, but that's why this question. It's a top-down code execution, so what's so special about the return statements?

Comment: Because the function returned from `useEffect` is called when the component is getting unmounted which is when `toggleVar` is changed from `true` to `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but why does it seem like the RETURN is not triggered immediately when the useEffect exits

because you are returning a function and React takes care of invoking it when one of two conditions apply:

a) the effect is ran again. The cleanup function is then invoked before the effect runs

b) the component unmounts

In your example, only case b) applies, because you are using `useEffect(..., [])` with an empty dependency array, meaning the effect is only ran on first render.

Therefore:

- You click the button the first time, `RandomComponent` is rendered, the effect runs and React stores the cleanup function
- You click it a second time, `RandomComponent` unmounts, therefore triggering the cleanup function

On successive clicks, this behavior repeats because a new `RandomComponent` is rendered.